# Installing WinPcap on Windows 8

Tags: compatibility, windows-8, wireshark, winpcap

I know there has been lots of discussion already on installing WinPcap on Windows 8.  I'm running the RTM version. I was able to install WinPcap without a hitch by using the Windows 7 compatibility mode.

Since then, I've noticed that WinPcap has stopped running and is actually no longer even installed.  I tried installing it again, but now it continues to tell me that WinPcap does not work with my version of Windows. Compatibility modes and admin privileges make no difference. The only thing I remember doing to my system was installed >900MBs of Windows Updates.

Does anyone have any ideas about what I might do to get WinPcap installed?

I've already ensured that the compatibility mode settings I changed were in effect for all users.

I've already ensured that "run this program as an administrator" is checked on the compatibility tab for all users.

I've also tried installing WinPcap 4.1.2 and 4.1.1. No success with either.

Answer (score 2):

URLSnooper's version of winPcap is not working with Windows 8, but from the WinPcap homepage, it says

> 8 March 2013:
>
> As of today, WinPcap 4.1.3 is available in the download section of the WinPcap website.
> This release adds support for Windows 8 and Server 2012

So it's safe to assume the latest version there works on windows 8. I have myself made it install without compatibility mode perfectly. It works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Other solution I found solution on Wireshark Q&A
https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/26361/loading-configuration-files

> but i resolved using this command.( in administrative dos command
>   prompt)
>
> ```
> sc config npf start= delayed-auto
> reboot
> ```

Answer (score 0):

WinPCap has no [instructions on their site](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__compilation.html) yet about compiling for Windows 8. I am guessing it is not "Officially" supported yet.

You can try to follow the instructions in the section named:

> **Compiling the driver for Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/2008/Win7/2008R2 (x86 and x64)**

and using the [Windows 8 Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852362) to build your own drivers and see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new 4.1.3 release of WinPcap, which includes changes to the installer to support Windows 8 (there aren't any other changes).